# Why are the symbolic (textual) coordinates misaligned in my pgfplots plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am creating a plot with pgfplots and using symbolic (textual) input coordinates. My MWE is as follows:

```
\providecommand{\myrootdir}{..}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\onlyifstandalone{
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=80mm,height=50mm,
        xtick=data,
        symbolic x coords={yellow, green, blue}]

        \addplot+[sharp plot]
        coordinates {(yellow, 2) (green, 1) (blue, 3)};
        \addplot+[sharp plot]
        coordinates {(yellow, 2.5) (green, 2) (blue, 3)};
        \addplot+[sharp plot]
        coordinates {(yellow, 3) (green, 3) (blue, 1)};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: A plot with misaligned input coordinates]

As you can see in the image, the input coordinate "green" is misaligned (too high). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input coordinate labels seem to get misaligned as the text is moved as close to the x axis as possible, disregarding the other labels.

As "green" does not contain any "high" letter, such as "l" in "yellow" and "b" or "l" in "blue", it can be moved closer to the axis.

To solve this, I used the workaround of capitalising all labels. Another possibility would be to reword the labels, if possible.

[image: A plot with well-aligned input coordinates]

*I am looking forward to a better solution, but I posted this question to be able to show one option for solving it that I used in my document. I hope it is helpful to some!*

Comment: add `text height=2ex` to `yticklabel style`

Comment: Do you mean the `xticklabel`? Either way, neither seem to work. :/

Comment: `xticklabel style={text height=3ex}` works for me \

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate. Have a look there how to solve this "problem".

Comment: If the question and/or the answer(s) are useful, feel free to [upvote](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) there ...